# Windows 7 paint brush tool

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-paint

They seem to have changed the paintbrush tool in windows 7 a little bit. Apparently, I'm no longer able to paint a pixel a different color on the spot. After clicking, the brush only comes into effect after I cross over to a second pixel, which basically means I can only paint 2 pixels and more, or none. Is there any way to change that up so that I can paint one pixel on the spot? This new thing is annoying and a waste of my time.

Also, the brush has tendencies to not fully implement color as I go along. For example, if I draw over a patch of black with white, some pixels may turn out grey or any other variant. Is there any way to make the colors opaque in one stroke? (I've noticed that the brush may paint a solid color occasionally, but but mixed colors show up more often than not.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the **Pencil** tool at its smallest size for accurate single pixel drawing with opaque colors.

The Brush tools use *antialiasing* which leads to the properties you describe and don't want.

Comment: I assume you mean pencil tool, as it does what I required. The brush tool did everything the pencil could in earlier versions, so using it never crossed my mind here. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I meant Pencil, not Pen. I have corrected my answer.